# Issues in Picasso Image Loading in Recycler View

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, picasso

Actually when i click on card view items it does not display images but data loaded exactly using `json` and `picasso` what is the error can any one solve this issue with your brilliance in `picasso` library?

```
public class SeconActivity extends Activity
{
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Shop> shops;
String serverUrl = "http://yoursubshop.com/webservices/categories-shop.php?    category=";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seocnd_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.secondmain);
    LinearLayoutManager ll = new LinearLayoutManager(SeconActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(ll);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String serverUrlId = in.getStringExtra("ks");
    serverUrl = serverUrl.concat(serverUrlId);
    new JsonTask().execute();
}

public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Shop>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Shop> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            String finaljson = sb.toString();
            JSONObject firstobject = new JSONObject(finaljson);
            JSONArray firstarray = firstobject.getJSONArray("data");
           /* List<Your> yo = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < firstarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalobject = firstarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Your y = new Your();
                y.setCategory_id(finalobject.getString("category_id"));
                y.setCategory_name(finalobject.getString("category_name"));
                yo.add(y);*/
            List<Shop> yo = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < firstarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalobject = firstarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Shop yos = new Shop();
                yos.shop_id = finalobject.getString("shop_id");
                yos.shop_name= finalobject.getString("shop_name");
                yos.Shop_logo=finalobject.getString("shop_logo");
                yo.add(yos);
            }
            return yo;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {

                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Shop> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Rvadapter listAdapter = new Rvadapter(SeconActivity.this, result);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}

public class Rvadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Rvadapter.Myadapter> {
    List<Shop> yours = Collections.emptyList();
    Context c;
    public class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
        CardView cv;
        public Myadapter(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopt);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopr);
            image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);

        }
    }
    public Rvadapter(Context c, List<Shop> yours) {
        this.yours = yours;
        this.c = c;
    }
    @Override
    public Myadapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shopss, parent, false);
        Myadapter m = new Myadapter(v);
        return m;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Myadapter holder, int position) {
        Shop  y = yours.get(position);
        holder.id.setText(y.shop_id);
        holder.name.setText(y.shop_name);
        Picasso.with(c)
                .load(y.Shop_logo)
                .into(holder.image);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return yours == null ? 0 : yours.size();
    }



       @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u get anything in `y.Shop_logo` ?

Comment: yes that is image refernce in Shop class

Comment: there should be a valid path

Comment: yes that is valid path

Comment: if the path valid and imageview is available then it should work.

Comment: i have a url like this http://www.yoursubshop.com/data//shop_logos//shop_logo_31032016150325.jpg.like this so many urls how can i give common url to all images to retrive iusing json

Answer (score 0):

when you use glide, The imageview size should be predefined or match parent. when glide couldn't estimate height or weight then it doesn't load anything. so put load for height and weight of imageview in adapter.

and more on that use picasso library to rectify issue if its really a dimention measurement problem.

from [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) you will get detailed guideline to differentiate between this two library.